# Use pydrive to list files using a variable holding the folder id's, in a loop

Tags: python, list, loops, variables, pydrive

I am using pyDrive to get a list of all files in specific folder id's. If I hard code the folder id, it works fine, but I'd like to use a loop, and cycle through a list of folder ID's. It might just be that I'm not formatting the variable into the command correctly.

This works fine....

```
file_list = drive.ListFile({'q': "'0B1fhQb9wymxEUUFGVXpfYlJhTk0' in parents and trashed=false"}).GetList()
```

But if I put that statement into a for loop to cycle through a list of folder ID's, it does not work. The '0B1fhQb9wymxEUUFGVXpfYlJhTk0' is the part I need to swap out for the variable in the for loop.

I've tried every kind of for loop I can find an example of on the net, and every kind of way to substitute the loop variable. Even tried putting the first half of the command in a string, the last half in another, and then "first + x + last", but that didn't work either.

```
for x in listofpersonfolders:
  file_list = drive.ListFile({'q': "\'x\' in parents and trashed=false"}).GetList()
  print file_list
```

and also tried

```
for x in listofpersonfolders:
  file_list = drive.ListFile({'q': "'x' in parents and trashed=false"}).GetList()
  print file_list
```

Comment: Please show us the for loop you tried.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
# Define string with placeholder for parent id.
request_template = "'{parent_id}' in parents and trashed=false"

for x in listofpersonfolders:
  # Replace the placeholder for parent_id with x in each iteration.
  file_list = drive.ListFile({'q': request_template.format(parent_id=x)}).GetList()
  print file_list
```

You can check out this website for more information on string formatting: https://pyformat.info/

Comment: Thank you for taking a moment to help. I tried that solution. Have tried a bunch of similar lines. This is what I got with this one.....sigh...my cut and paste was 800+ char too long, it returned "Invalid query" Thank you for pointing me to pyformat.info. Will check that out.

Comment: No problem! I just double-checked the query and I think found the error: the folder ID has to be surrounded by quotes. This is now changed - maybe try again?

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution

```
for x in listofpersonfolders:
    file_list = drive.ListFile({'q': "'{}' in parents and trashed=false".format(x)}).GetList()
print file_list
```